# Как заставить работать псевдоклассы css в React?

Tags: css, reactjs

Я импортирую стили в компоненты React через import

```
import './Style.css';
```

При этом у меня не работают псевдоклассы из стилей

```
.DepartmentList__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  background-color: seagreen;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.DepartmentList__link :before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-color: seagreen;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: -7px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Слишком мало информации. Можешь часть кода с псевдоклассами для начала?

Comment: @AlexOrtizzz `.DepartmentList__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    background-color: seagreen;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.DepartmentList__link :before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-color: seagreen;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: -7px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}`

Comment: на самом деле они работают, просто не к тем элементам, которые ты ожидаешь, применяются

Comment: @Grundy да, применяются, только к потомкам. Аналогом будет `.someClass *:before`

Comment: @AlexOrtizzz, можешь дописать это в свой ответ, а то сейчас кажется, что их всегда нужно слитно писать

Answer (score 1):

В твоем случае псевдоклассы применяются к потомкам. Чтобы псевдокласс применялся именно к `.DepartmentList__link`, нужно писать его слитно с этим классом:

```
.DepartmentList__link:before {
    ...
}
```

Comment: спасибо, изивини за тупой вопрос